# How can I find whether a row exists using a `SELECT` query in python MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to check if a specific row exists in a database using a `SELECT` query. If it doesn't, I want to `INSERT INTO` the database with another query. If it does, I don't want anything to happen.

I am thinking to use an if statement in Python to handle the scenario above, but I can't find how I can make a `SELECT` query return True or False based on whether the row is found or not.

I'm using MySQLdb

```
   def _query (self, query):
     cursor = self.db.cursor()
     cursor.execute (query)
     return cursor
```

---

```
      for k,v in sorted(config.items()):
  
    #checking for duplicate values
  
    check_items_table = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE text = ('%s') AND name = ('%s')" % \
    (str (k), str (v))
    self._query (check_items_table)
  
    if check_items_table == <True or False or Something>:

      #do nothing

    else:

      #insert into items table

      items_table = "INSERT INTO items(item_id, \
      name, text) \
      VALUES (null,'%s', '%s')" % \
      (str (k), str (v))
      self._query (items_table)
```

Comment: Is `self._query` a `psycopg2.cursor`? If it is, then you can do something like: `self._query.rowcount`. It will return the number of rows that you get from your query.

Comment: It doesnt use the `psycopg2 class`. `_query` just creates a cursor object and uses the execute method: `cursor.execute (query)`

Comment: @Paco: It's probably not a psycopg2.cursor if he's using MySQL…

Comment: @LaneFujikado: It would really help if you showed the code for `_query` instead of just vaguely describing it. And told us which MySQL module you're using.

Comment: @abarnert, oh yeah, my bad. But it should something pretty similar anyway.

Comment: @LaneFujikado: You can't (usefully) paste code into comments on StackOverflow; it loses all the formatting. And besides, it's always better to edit the question to make it a better question, than to leave it incomplete and have a bunch of comments below.

Comment: If you have a UNIQUE constraint or one of the columns is a primary key, then you can use [`INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: As a side note, it's always a bad idea to build SQL strings dynamically, like your `check_items_table`. It leaves you open to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/), forces you to deal with fiddly quoting/escaping/type-conversion problems, and prevents the database from realizing that you're running the same query repeatedly. Use parameterized statements instead.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: It's even simpler than that; he just wants to do nothing if the row already exists. So either `INSERT IGNORE`, or just plain `INSERT` and handle the error.

Answer (score 3):

You're using MySQLdb, which is [DB-API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)-compliant.

You're calling `execute`, then returning the [`Cursor`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects) object.

Cursors have an attribute [`rowcount`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount), but in some database modules, that's only set for modification queries like `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, not for `SELECT`, and in others, it's only set after you do a `fetch*` operation. (I believe MySQLdb is one of the latter, but I'm not positive.)

So, what you want to to is to call the [`fetchone`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) method. If it returns a row, the row exists; if it raises an exception, the row doesn't exist.

---

Alternatively, instead of selecting the row itself, you could `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM …`. Then `fetchone` is guaranteed to return one row with one value, which will be either 0 or 1.

---

However, I'm not sure you want to do things this way in the first place. Usually, it's better to create a unique constraint on the column (or columns), so the database won't allow two rows to exist with the same values for that column. Then, you can just `INSERT` the row, and you'll get an error if it already exists; no need for a `SELECT` at all. (Or, if you don't need to know whether it already existed, you can use [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html), which is MySQL-specific.)

---

Meanwhile, to expand on my side note:

It's always a bad idea to build SQL strings dynamically, like this:

```
items_table = "INSERT INTO items(item_id, \
      name, text) \
      VALUES (null,'%s', '%s')" % \
      (str (k), str (v))
```

This leaves you open to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/), forces you to deal with fiddly quoting/escaping/type-conversion problems, and prevents the database from realizing that you're running the same query repeatedly.

Use parameterized statements instead. Like this:

```
items_table = "INSERT INTO items(item_id, \
      name, text) \
      VALUES (null, %s, %s)"
```

Notice that I didn't quote the `%s`'s, and I didn't use a `%` operator. The values get sent to the [`execute`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) statement:

```
cursor.execute(items_table, (k, v))
```

So, you just need to update your `_query` wrapper like this:

```
def _query(self, query, parameters=[]):
     cursor = self.db.cursor()
     cursor.execute(query, parameters)
     return cursor
```

… and you can call it like this:

```
self._query(items_table, (k, v))
```

Comment: As an optimization, instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` you can use a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` clause since you're only interested if any row exists, not the count which may be expensive.  It probably won't give you much in this case though as the count is expected to be <= 1.

Comment: @AustinPhillips: Good point. In the case where you expect exactly 1 row, `COUNT(*)` seems to go faster than `LIMIT 1`… but the difference is pretty small, and they're both so far that you'd rarely ever care. And if you haven't created a unique constraint (in which case you wouldn't even need this code…), it may be better to take the tiny hit in code that's too fast to care about than the risk of an unexpected huge hit. So, I agree. However, I was suggesting `COUNT(*)` for the _simplicity_ benefit—you always get exactly one row with one column—rather than any performance benefit.